# Select element with special character with regex and Python

Tags: python, regex

From a list of strings ('16','160','1,2','100,11','1','16:','16:00'), I want to keep only the elements that

1. either have a comma between two digits (e.g. 1,2 or 100,11)
2. or have two digits (without comma) that are NOT followed by ":" (i.e. followed by nothing: e.g 16, or followed by anything but ":": e.g. 160)

I tried the following code using regex in Python:

```
import re
string = ['16','160','1,2','100,11','1','16:','16:00']
pattern_rate = re.compile(r'(?:[\d],[\d]|[\d][\d][^:]*)')
rate = list(filter(pattern_rate.search,string))
print(rate)
```

Print:

> ['16', '160', '1,2','100,11' '16:', '16:00']

To be correct, the script should keep the first three items and reject the rest, but my script fails at rejecting the last two items. I guess I'm using the "[^:]" sign incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To be correct, the script should keep the first three items and reject
> the rest,

You can match either 2 or more digits, or match 2 digits with a comma in between.

As the list contains only numbers, you could use [re.match](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) to start the match at the beginning of the string instead of [re.search](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search).

```
(?:\d{2,}|\d,\d)\Z
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\d{2,}` Match 2 or more digits
  - `|` Or
  - `\d,\d` Match 2 digits with a comma in between
- `)` Close non capture group
- `\Z` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/m8zWIw/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/x3WEnQ)

```
import re
string = ['16','160','1,2','100,11','1','16:','16:00']
pattern_rate = re.compile(r'(?:\d{2,}|\d,\d)\Z')
rate = list(filter(pattern_rate.match,string))
print(rate)
```

Output

```
['16', '160', '1,2']
```

Comment: Thank you. Btw do I really need the non-capturing group ? I copy/pasted this from another example, but it looks like it does not change anything, right?

Comment: @AnthonyHauser You need the grouping, you can make it a capture group instead using just `()` but you don't need the capture group value. The match by itself is enough. If you don't use the grouping, you can get partial matches. See https://regex101.com/r/4VdJCj/1

Comment: So I need the "()" in order to add the "\Z" at the end that applies to both conditions? Otherwise I don't understand your example.

Comment: @AnthonyHauser Exactly. If you don't use the grouping, the pattern matches either `^\d{2,}` or  `\d,\d\Z` *(As it makes use of re.match which already matches at the start of the string you can omit `^`)*

Comment: But why did you add the "^"? Shouldn't search to any character except "\d{2,}" with the "^"?

Comment: @AnthonyHauser The pattern `^(?:\d{2,}|\d,\d)$` is for the example on regex101. Here, the `^` is an anchor which asserts the start of the string. The `$` asserts the end of the string. As re.match starts at the beginning of the string, we can omit `^` You use the grouping mechanism to specify that all of the alternatives in the grouping separated by the pipe should be between the start and the end of the string. If you don't use the grouping, is says match either this at the start of the string, or either this at the end of the string. `[^]`changes the meaning and is a negated character class.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend looking a bit deeper into a regex guide.

100 is not a digit and will not match `\d`. Also having groups `[..]` with one element inside is not necessary if you don't intend to negate or otherwise transform them.

The first query can be represented by `(?:\d+,\d+)`. It's a non-capturing group, that detects comma-separated numbers of length greater equal to one.

Your second query will show anything matching three consecutive digits following any (*) amount of not colons.

You'll want to use something similar to `(?:\d{2,}(?!:))`. It's a non-capturing group, matching digits with length greater equal to two, that are not followed by a colon. `?!` designates a negative lookahead.

In your python code, you'll want to use `pattern_rate.match` instead of `pattern_rate.find` as the latter one will return partial matches while the first one only returns full matches.

```
pattern_rate = re.compile(r'(?:\d+,\d+)|(?:\d{2,}(?!:))')
rate = list(filter(pattern_rate.match, string))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm not sure to understand why you mention '100 is not a digit and will not match \d' in the context of my question. Regarding the second query, I wrote two consecutive '\d', so it should show anything matching two consecutive digits, no?

Comment: `[\d],[\d]` wouldn't match 100,10. Only single digit numbers.

Comment: Instead the second part will match anything starting with 2 digits and not followed by colon, e.g. 10,40,120Kappa

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you need regex for that:

```
string = ['16','160','1,2','100,11','1','16:','16:00']

keep = []

for elem in string:
    if ("," in elem and len(elem) == 3) or ( ":" not in elem and "," not in elem and len(elem) >= 2):
        keep.append(elem)

print (keep)
```

Output:

```
['16', '160', '1,2']
```

Although not that much elegant, tends to be faster than using regex.